# How to figure out the live chat widget of websites?

Tags: chat, widgets

If you would take a look at this website.

https://haystack.report/

It uses a pretty interesting chat support widget.

How to figure out the company that made this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about the underlying technology of a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the chat button (in this case, the balloon thingy) and select the option "Inspect Element" (or similar). It is available in most desktop browsers (I tried Chrome, Firefox, Edge, they all had it), and should be available in mobile browsers, as well.

You should see something like `<div class="intercom-launcher-close-icon">`. Searching for "intercom launcher" returned [this result](https://www.intercom.com/live-chat) from a company that offers live chat as a service for websites.

The rationale behind this procedure is that live chat provider usually gives its customers the same piece of HTML code to put on their websites, and this HTML code carries the provider's signature.

Comment: Very clever! A wonder I didn't think of finding it out in this way, I was befuddled as I used 'view source' instead of 'inspect element' and couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: It is basically the same thing, but "view-source" throws way too much code in response. If you can see the element you are looking for (sometimes it's hidden), it is always better to use "inspect element".